# On using "to what extent there exist"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

Is the phrase

> to what extent there exist

a correct phrase? For example:

> To what extent there exist disadvantaged families in this area?

I searched on it in google but did not find it used. So I am not sure if it is correct or not? Is there a better way to ask about the existence of a phenomenon in scientific research context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a form of the verb "*to do*" in there somewhere:

> To what extent *does* there exist disadvantaged families in this area?

That's a bit unusual though. It would be more idiomatic if you said:

> To what extent *do* disadvantaged families exist in this area?